# Ajax Timer Couses Text Selection (RadGrid Column Label) Lose

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, timer, radgrid

Please take a look at my aspx codes :

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="grd_transactions" runat="server" GroupPanelPosition="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Skin="WebBlue">
                    <GroupingSettings CollapseAllTooltip="Collapse all groups"></GroupingSettings>
                    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="True">
                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                    </ClientSettings>
                    <MasterTableView>
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Type column" HeaderText="Type" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Type">
                                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="100px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Type" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>' Font-Size="15px" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Type").ToString() == "Payout" ? "Payout" : "Deposit" %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Height="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Date_Time_UTC_GMT column" HeaderText="Date &amp; Time (UTC/GMT)" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Date_Time_UTC_GMT">
                                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="200px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Date_Time_UTC_GMT" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date Time UTC GMT") %>' Font-Size="15px" ToolTip="Date &amp; Time (UTC/GMT)"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Height="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_BTC_Investment_Address column" HeaderText="BTC Investment Address" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_BTC_Investment_Address">
                                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="450px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <a id="link_BTC_Investment_Address" class="link_BTC_Investment_Address_class" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href='<%# Eval("BTC Investment URL") %>'>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_BTC_Investment_Address" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BTC Investment Address") %>' Font-Size="15px" ToolTip='<%# Eval("BTC Investment URL") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </a>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Height="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Deposit_Amount column" HeaderText="Deposit Amount" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Deposit_Amount">
                                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="200px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Deposit_Amount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Deposit Amount") %>' Font-Size="15px" ToolTip="Deposit Amount In Bitcoin"></asp:Label>
                                    &nbsp;
                        <asp:Image ID="img_Deposit_Amount" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/bitcoin-doubler-icon-for-table-btc.png" ToolTip="Deposit Amount In Bitcoin" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Height="50px" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Payout_Amount column" HeaderText="Payout Amount" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Payout_Amount">
                                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="200px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Payout_Amount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Payout Amount") %>' Font-Size="15px" ToolTip="Payout Amount In Bitcoin"></asp:Label>
                                    &nbsp;
                        <asp:Image ID="img_Payout_Amount" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/bitcoin-doubler-icon-for-table-btc.png" ToolTip="Payout Amount In Bitcoin" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Height="50px" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Status column" HeaderText="Status" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Status">
                                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="250px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Status" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' Font-Size="15px" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Status").ToString() == "Complete" ? "Double payment completed" : "Time left for double payment" %>'></asp:Label>
                                    &nbsp;
                                <asp:Image ID="img_Status" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Status").ToString() == "Complete" ? "~/Images/bitcoin-doubler-payout_icon.png" : "~/Images/bitcoin-doubler-clock-flat.png" %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("Status").ToString() == "Complete" ? "Complete" : "On Timer" %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Height="50px" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </MasterTableView>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here is c# Timer1_Tick:

```
 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridDataItem item in grd_transactions.Items)
        {
            Label lbl_Type_control = item.FindControl("lbl_Type") as Label;
            Label lbl_Status_control = item.FindControl("lbl_Status") as Label;
            Image img_Status_control = item.FindControl("img_Status") as Image;

            if (lbl_Status_control.Text != "Complete")
            {
                string[] time_array = lbl_Status_control.Text.Split(':');
                int hours = Convert.ToInt32(time_array[0]);
                int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(time_array[1]);
                int seconds = Convert.ToInt32(time_array[2]);
                int time_left_seconds = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;
                if (time_left_seconds > 0)
                {
                    time_left_seconds = time_left_seconds - 1;
                    TimeSpan timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time_left_seconds);
                    lbl_Status_control.Text = timespan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                    //lbl_Status_control.Text = timespan.ToString("H:mm:ss");
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl_Type_control.Text = "Payout";
                    lbl_Type_control.ToolTip = "Payout";

                    lbl_Status_control.Text = "Complete";
                    lbl_Status_control.ToolTip = "Double payment completed";

                    img_Status_control.ImageUrl = "~/Images/bitcoin-doubler-payout_icon.png";
                    img_Status_control.ToolTip = "Complete";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

In timer_tick i create countdown clock `(hh\:mm\:ss)` & change RadGird Status column's label in every 1 second tick.

---

The problem is when a user select a row or select label's text inside a column by mouse in every tick selection vanishes & user lose the selection & feels the tick of timer.
What trick should i use to fix this problem?

Comment: If your timer is handled server-side, does this mean the page is reloading with every timer tick?  That would certainly cause state to be lost.  As a general architectural concern you may want to move this logic into JavaScript on the page, since it doesn't look like there's any dependency on the server here.

Comment: @David I should add some extra codes in timer & when status is complete i want write something on database. So i need that timer in server-side.

Comment: @David you are a hard worker on stack. Thanks for helping people.